# Problems with Binding to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have the code which generate gridview with usercontrols:

```
 <ListView x:Name="ListView" SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                            <UserControls:ItemTemplateControl Parametr="XXXXXXX"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Listview works fine but i can't send anything to my UserControl. 
UserControl code:

```
public sealed partial class ItemTemplateControl : UserControl
    {
        public string Parametr
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(ParametrProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ParametrProperty, value);
            }
        }
        public static DependencyProperty ParametrProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Parametr", typeof(string), typeof(ItemTemplateControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));


        public ItemTemplateControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            post_text.Text = Parametr;
            Get();
        }
```

This code doesn't work! I don't now where is the problem?

Sorry for my English

```
<Page
    x:Class="App13.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App13"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:UserControls="using:App13.UserControls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
```

Comment: Please include the xaml header for this question. Your issue could be that you haven't opened the `ItemTemplateControl` namespace correctly in xaml.

Comment: There is no error in the code

Comment: where are you setting the itemsSource of the listview

Comment: Some errors don't show up in any output. I'm not familiar with the "using:" method of importing namespaces that you've used. Since there's nothing obviously wrong I'd change it to be like xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App13" and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: In my MainPage.xaml.cs code

Comment: @Craig Graham No it's a win store app I can't use xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App13"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to register a callback for when the dependency property `Parametr` changes. To do this you must:

```
public static DependencyProperty ParametrProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Parametr", typeof(string), typeof(ItemTemplateControl), new PropertyMetadata("", ParametrChanged));
```

And define some logic in the `ParametrChanged` method

```
private static void ParametrChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
       var sender = d as ItemTemplateControl;
       if (sender == null) return;

       var newValue = e.NewValue as string;
       sender.post_text.Text = newValue;
}
```

Comment: I can use value in ParametrChanged method, but can i use it in my own method?

Comment: I would do the opposite: call "my own method" (instance method on the ItemTemplateControl class) from ParametrChanged. Does this make sense?

To expand on this: you can define a private method on your class and from the callback invoke it on the `sender`. In that private method you can access the property `Parametr` and it should contain the updated value.